# p:textEditor error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having trouble with the p:textEditor component of the Primefaces framework.
A context menu displays a p:dialog that allows you to enter text in a p:textEditor whose initialization is problematic.
I'm having trouble with the p:textEditor component of the Primefaces framework.
A context menu displays a p:dialog that allows you to enter text in a p:textEditor whose initialization is problematic.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my code and the error caused after:

```
      <p:contextMenu beforeShow="pageC()">     
                <p:menuitem value="Ajouter une note" 
                            actionListener="#{noteManagerBean.nouvelleNote()}"   <---------- 
                            oncomplete="PF('widgetNoteDialog').show()" 
                            update="idNoteDialog"/>
            </p:contextMenu>

            <p:dialog id="idNoteDialog" widgetVar="widgetNoteDialog>
              ...
                <p:textEditor id="idTexte" value="#{noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee.texte}" placeholder="Entrez votre texte ici" height="129" style="width: 294px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 12px; margin-left: -1px; background-color: transparent">
                        <f:facet name="toolbar"> 
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                            </span>
                        </f:facet>
                </p:textEditor>
```

And my bean code

```
    public void nouvelleNote() {  <---------- noteManagerBean

        setNoteSelectionnee(new UtiNote());

        getNoteSelectionnee().setRefUtilisateurFk(getRefUtilisateurFacade().getUtilisateur().getIdPk());
        getNoteSelectionnee().setPage("pageTableauContributeur");
        getNoteSelectionnee().setElement(null);
        getNoteSelectionnee().setType("N");
        getNoteSelectionnee().setTexte(null);       <---------- same problem with: setTexte("") , setTexte(new String())
        getNoteSelectionnee().setCouleur("Jaune");
        getNoteSelectionnee().setCouleurHexa("FFFA6D");
        getNoteSelectionnee().setPositionX(getNoteDialogLeft());
        getNoteSelectionnee().setPositionY(getNoteDialogTop());
    }



    @Entity
@Table(name = "UtiNote")
public class UtiNote implements Serializable {         <---------- UtiNote entity

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPk;
    private int refUtilisateurFk;
    private String page;
    private String element;
    private String type;
    private String texte;     <--------------- 
    private String couleur;
    private String couleurHexa;
    private String positionX;
    private String positionY;

    public UtiNote() {
    }
    + GETTER/SETTER
```

Error :

```
Infos: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /templateNote.xhtml @70,261 value="#{noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee.texte}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /templateNote.xhtml @70,261 value="#{noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee.texte}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:146)
at org.primefaces.component.texteditor.TextEditorRenderer.getConvertedValue(TextEditorRenderer.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:424)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
```

Comment: How do you define `noteSelectionnee` in `noteManagerBean` ?

Comment: like this : private UtiNote noteSelectionnee;

Comment: do you have a getter for this attribute (`getNoteSelectionnee`) ?

Comment: Next time post errors from stacktraces in a searchengine and see what all comes up. You can even add (e.g. in Google) site:stackoverflow.com to limit your search to this great site.

Comment: Yes getter/setter

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that `noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee.texte` throws a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`. This happens because `getNoteSelectionnee()` returns a null value. I guess the error occurs whe first loading the page, so you should change your text editor's tag code to:

```
<p:textEditor id="idTexte"
              value="#{noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee.texte}" 
              placeholder="Entrez votre texte ici" 
              height="129" 
              style="..."
              rendered="#{not empty noteManagerBean.noteSelectionnee}"
              >
```

This way it will not fail *before* `noteSlectionnee` is set.